How to find the nth term(2,3,4 and so on) of a series in the Faulhaber's formula?
Hi if I have this series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{p}=1^{p}+2^{p}+3^{p}+....+n^{p}$$ How can I apply the formula of Faulhaber's without using calculus and just combinatorics and precalculus?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{p} = \frac{1}{p+1} * \sum_{r=0}^{p} \binom{p+1}{k} B_r*n^{p-r+1} $$
If $$p=2,3,4,5,6$$
How can I apply this formula and who is $B_r$ in the formula?
If it's the Bernoulli number what formula do I use?
Wikipedia showed me a lot of formulas for Bernoulli but I don't know which one to apply for this formula!
Also is there a proof for the Faulhaber's formula for series?
Later edit: This is what I found on Bernoulli number without calculus:



See this duplicate for Bernoulli numbers $B_r$.

@DietrichBurde I did specified without calculus....

But you are also using precalculus by forming a sum and using binomial coefficients. It makes no sense for Bernoulli numbers without this.

This Numberphile video might interest you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83NFR7JDlww

What you found is not without calculus. Look at the proof of it.

@DietrichBurde Ok I thought that you can use combinatorics and summation without differentiation and integration.I give up!

(I may have already
submitted this,
but I can't find it.)
Here's a way
of generating the successive formulas
for the sums of powers
I came up with
a while ago.
This is obviously not original,
and was probably known to Bernoulli,
but it was found independently
by me.
If
$f_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$
($f_0(n) = n$)
then
$\begin{array}\\
f_k(n+1) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^k\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{so}\\
(n+1)^k
&=f_{k}(n+1)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
kf_{k-1}(n)
&=(n+1)^k-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
(k+1)f_{k}(n)
&=(n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
f_{k}(n)
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\left((n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)\right)\\
\end{array}
$
Note that
this shows that
if $f_j(n)$
is a polynomial of degree $j+1$
for $0 \le j \le k-1$
then
$f_k(n)$
is a polynomial of degree
$k+1$.
Here are the first few cases.
$\begin{array}\\
\\
k=1\\
2f_{1}(n)
&=(n+1)^{2}-1-f_0(n)\\
&=n^2+2n+1-1-n\\
&=n^2+n\\
f_1(n)
&=\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}\\
\\
k=2\\
3f_{2}(n)
&=(n+1)^{3}-1-f_0(n)-3f_1(n)\\
&=n^3+3n^2+3n+1-1-n-3(n^2+n)/2\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+6n^2+6n+2-2-2n-3(n^2+n)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{2}\\
f_{2}(n)
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}\\
\\
k=3\\
4f_{3}(n)
&=(n+1)^{4}-1-f_0(n)-4f_1(n)-6f_2(n)\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1-1-n-4\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}-6\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+3n-2(n^2+n)-(2n^3+3n^2+n)\\
&=n^4+2n^3+n^2\\
&=n^2(n^2+2n+1)\\
&=n^2(n+1)^2\\
f_3(n)
&=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\\
\\
k=4\\
5f_{4}(n)
&=(n+1)^{5}-1-f_0(n)-5f_1(n)-10f_2(n)-10f_3(n)\\
&=n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1-1-n-5\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}-10\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}-10\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\\
&=n^5 + \dfrac{5 n^4}{2} + \dfrac{5 n^3}{3} - \dfrac{n}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{6n^5 + 15 n^4 + 10 n^3 - n}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{ n (2 n + 1) (n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)}{6}\\
f_4(n)
&=\dfrac{ n (2 n + 1) (n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)}{30}\\
&=\dfrac{6n^5 + 15 n^4 + 10 n^3 - n}{30}\\
&=\dfrac{n^5}{5} + \dfrac{ n^4}{2} + \dfrac{ n^3}{3} - \dfrac{n}{30}\\
\end{array}
$
